# Upload File in Edit Multiple Data Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create an edit multiple data form [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOfmf.png) using Laravel 8. In the form, you could upload only one file for each row. I could update the data without uploading file, but when I tried to update the file, it redirect me back to the form and no file uploaded. I already add enctype to my form. This is my code:

View:

```
<div class="custom-file" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
   <input type="file" name="bukti[]" class="custom-file-input">
   <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
if($request->file('bukti') !=null) {
  //upload file
  $bukti=array();
  if($files=$request->file('bukti')) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
     $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
     $path=$file->storeAs('blabla',$name);
     $bukti[]=$name;
  }
}
    
//Update multiple data
if(count($request->id) > 0) {
  foreach($request->id as $item => $v) {
    $data = array(
      'id_laporan' => $laporan_indikators->id,
      'id_pertanyaan' => $request->id_pertanyaan[$item],
      'jumlah' => $request->jumlah[$item],
      'keterangan' => $request->keterangan[$item],
      'bukti' => $bukti[$item],
    );
    $data_laporans = DataLaporan::where('id',$request->id[$item])->first();
    $data_laporans->update($data);
  }
 }
```

I already tried to fix it but I still didn't get a solution. Please help me because I'm still a beginner. I'm sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I already tried to update the code to something like this:

Controller:

```
//upload file
if($files=$request->file('bukti')) {
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $name=$file->hashName();
    $path=$file->storeAs('blabla',$name);
    $bukti=$name;
  }
}
    
//Update multiple data
if(count($request->id) > 0) {
   foreach($request->id as $item => $v) {
     $data = array(
       'id_laporan' => $laporan_indikators->id,
       'id_pertanyaan' => $request->id_pertanyaan[$item],
       'jumlah' => $request->jumlah[$item],
       'keterangan' => $request->keterangan[$item],
       'bukti' => $bukti,
     );
     $data_laporans = DataLaporan::where('id',$request->id[$item])->first();
     $data_laporans->update($data);
   }
}
```

It uploaded the file and redirect me back to the index page after updating successfully, but when I check the database, the controller updated all of the bukti column value to the same file name. If I tried to update file for two rows, all of the bukti column is just update the value to the last uploaded file name. What I want is there's just one data for jumlah, keterangan, and one bukti file in a row, so I can have different files for each row. I don't really know how to fix this because I'm still a beginner. Thank you for your help.

Comment: **Note**: You Are Saving each file with the same name, and every file you upload gets overridden except the last one. you can fix this by: `$name = time() . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension()`. though you can add a random number along with the time, since files could be uploaded in less than a second.

Comment: @AdisonMasih Hi, I already tried it by change the `getClientOriginalExtension` to `getClientOriginalName`. It's upload my file and insert the file name to the database successfully, but I got this error when submit, `Undefined offset: 1`. in this line `'bukti' => $bukti[$item],` It happened when I tried to upload a file only for a row. It should redirect me back to the index page after submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for some times, finally I found a solution. Actually, I just need to give a condition if a file is uploaded in certain row.

View:

```
<div class="custom-file" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
   <input type="file" name="bukti_{{ $data->id }}" class="custom-file-input">
   <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
if (count($request->id) > 0) {
  $bukti = '';
  foreach ($request->id as $item => $v) {
    $id_item = $request->id[$item];
            
    $file = $request->file('bukti_'.$id_item);
    $data = array(
      'id_laporan' => $laporan_indikators->id,
      'id_pertanyaan' => $request->id_pertanyaan[$item],
      'jumlah' => $request->jumlah[$item],
      'keterangan' => $request->keterangan[$item],
                
    );
     //If file is updated
     if ($file) {            
       $name = $file->hashName();
       $path = $file->storeAs('blabla', $name);
       $bukti = $name;
       $data['bukti'] = $name;
     }
     $data_laporans = DataLaporan::where('id', $request->id[$item])->first();
     $data_laporans->update($data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the double question (??) mark for check whether the index of array is available or not:

```php
<?php

if($request->file('bukti') !=null) {
  //upload file
  $bukti=array();
  if($files=$request->file('bukti')) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
     $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
     $path=$file->storeAs('blabla',$name);
     $bukti[]=$name;
  }
}
    
//Update multiple data
if(count($request->id) > 0) {
  foreach($request->id as $item => $v) {
    $data = array(
      'id_laporan' => $laporan_indikators->id,
      'id_pertanyaan' => $request->id_pertanyaan[$item],
      'jumlah' => $request->jumlah[$item],
      'keterangan' => $request->keterangan[$item],
      'bukti' => $bukti[$item] ?? '',
    );
    $data_laporans = DataLaporan::where('id',$request->id[$item])->first();
    $data_laporans->update($data);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, @Rifki, I already tried your solution. It could update the file name correctly in database, but the value is become empty for the row that not have file upload. What I want is keeping the old value in database when there's no file uploaded. This is the result in database: https://imgur.com/a/inVq5a0. Please help, thank you

Comment: And also, when I tried to upload file for the third row, it will updated the first row and the other row will be empty. Please help me @Rifki